# Ajax / jQuery to PHP and back again?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I have an ajax call made with jQuery, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: data,
    success: function(response){
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

I get data from PHP like this:

```
$data_array = get_data();
foreach($data_array as $data)
{
    echo $data;
}
```

**PHP to slow**

The PHP data function call is slow because it gets very much data from the database, might fetch images, make some json calls and other slow things.

**One loop round at the time**

Therefor I need to get the PHP code just do one round, then Javascript and then do the next round in the loop.

**More than one way to solve it?**

There might be more than one way to do it. Which one is prefered? Javascript foreach-loop, JSON and global Javascript variables comes to mind.

Comment: What is a JSON **call**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the return type in your ajax function as xml or json, and then return you array in either of these types. I feel that JSON js the preferred one for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm slightly against storing actual images in the database.  I prefer to only keep a unique link for them and then return that instead of the actual image.  This would speed the query up a fair bit.  I agree with mad_programmer that the JSON js would be preferred for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could manipulate your query to do a limit. So something like:

```
 var total_count = ajax_get_sql('select statement with count');
 var curr_count = 0;
 var set_number = 10; 
 var select_statement_without_limit = 'statement';  

 setTimeout('fetch_data()',0);

 ...

 function fetch_data()
 {
      if(curr_count < total_count)
      {
           ajax_get_sql(select_statement_without_limit with limit appended);
           curr_count = curr_count + set_number;
           setTimeout('fetch_data()',0);
      }
 }
```

With all your ajax calls set to wait for a response instead of continuing.  I would keep the sql logic in PHP, but use javascript to query the server many times.  This will prevent your JS script from giving long execution errors.  I haven't really taken into account data manipulation, but you can probably figure it out!