# How to pass a value to PHP and return the processed results using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

In my project there is a process.php which is process the data according to the GET input.
For instance:

If scandir.php?page=5 , it will return an encoded json object which is an multidimensional array.

Now I am modifying the ajax part, how to call the php , assign the value to php and have the results returned and display?

Below is the example code I found from tutorial site, it doesn't seems pass any value to the php file ?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="prev"></div>
  <div id="curr"></div>
  <div id="next"></div>  
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       var url = 'scandir.php?' + 'page=5';
        $.getJSON(url , null,
          function(data) {
            $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
              console.log(item);
            });
          });
    });
​</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The json object sample created by the PHP file

```
{"prev":["","demo\/medium\/Web081112_P001_medium.jpg"],"curr":["demo\/medium\/Web081112_P002_medium.jpg","demo\/medium\/Web081112_P003_medium.jpg"],"next":["demo\/medium\/Web081112_P004_medium.jpg","demo\/medium\/Web081112_P005_medium.jpg"]}
```

Comment: Don't you need  $(document).ready(function(){}) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770701/ajax-jquery-to-php-and-back-again

Comment: I have edited the question, you can see the output from php file should be like that (the file path / ' ') value . What i process in php is just getting the process.php?value=i, base on the i , generate this output

Comment: You wrote `data.items`, it should be just `data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do it like this:

```
var url = 'process.php?' + 'value='1 + yourValue;


$.getJSON(url , null,
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $(item).appendTo("#results");
    });
  });
```

Comment: Since it is a multidimensional array, and the size is fixed, it should be only have 3 row in the array and the value are interger only, is there someway to manipulate it? thanks

Comment: The sample is [key1]=>4,5 ,[key2]=>5,1 , [key3]=>1,''

Comment: @user782104 I do not understand your comment. Please clarify. What exactly is multidimensional array?

Comment: @user782104 Where does key1 go?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you , i have edited the question

Comment: @user782104 Thanks, but what does this do: ... {"prev": ...

Comment: To make it simple , can I define three <div> eg. The first <div id ="prev"> , The second <div id = "current">... Then the js call ajax to get this json and display in the corresponding <div>?

Comment: The sample output
<div id="prev>"","demo/medium/Web081112_P001_medium.jpg"</div>

Comment: @user782104 And so you want to know how to you get the first element that is returned by $.getJSON() into <div id ="prev">, the second into <div id ="current">, etc?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20598/discussion-between-user782104-and-teodor-talov)

Answer (score 0):

To pass the values to the PHP function use AJAX JQuery ie $.ajax and success call back use  $.parseJSON to encode the data .

```
       $.ajax({
         url: url,
         data: {param1:value1,p1:v2},
         success: function(data){
               var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
               alert(obj.index); //access the indivisual value of the variable

         }
      });
```

Comment: I have edited the question, can I display the returned json object in the different <div>?

Comment: Yes. you can as you got the json obj u can put this values in div using $.("div").html(obj.index)